Actual nuance of 堪える in this sentence_
勘弁してくれよ! お前に泣かれるのは... 堪える
The character exclaims this as his girlfriend starts to cry to him and begs him to tell her secret.
The sentence ends with a simple" 堪える without any other particles, so I was wondering what is the actual nuance of 堪える?

勘弁してくれよ! お前に泣かれるのは

"Give me a break! You crying to me..." Given the context I suppose it's akin to "As I could endure you crying!" but why 堪える is used without any kind of particles by the end?

See [What does this mean in this context ? 結構堪える A character's thought about a girl when she's keeping a distance from him, while sitting with him
